# max_user_connections error meaning and fixing

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error from mysql:
"Unable to connect to database [User xyzxyz already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections"

My current max_user_connections=50, and I am running on a VPS

As a first step (I read somewhere that it should help) I created a new mysql user that will handle all the background operations which are the majority of the operations on my site. So now I have 2 users:

- xyzxyz_backgrounds- handling background operations
- xyzxyz_users - handling only mysql calls generated from users of the actual site.

Still after that change users are reporting getting "xyzxyz_users already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections"

This is a busy site that I running, but I wonder if I don't have a mistake in the code that is causing this.

I tried running "SHOW PROCESSLIST" and "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST", but I only see 2 rows that are returned (one SLEEP and one QUERY of the the show processlist).

As far I know, I don't have any type of persistent mysql connections

Below is the code that I use the start the mysql connection at the head of each php file (using 'require')

```
if (!(isset($use_pdo))) {
  $conn_mls = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
  mysql_select_db($dbname);
  mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

}else{
    $options = array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    );
    $dsn = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8";
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser , $dbpass , $options);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

};
```

In some cases I use mysqli, I don't think I use persist connections there, I can post the code if required.

When does mysql create a new connection? 
If I have max_user_connections=50 does it mean that only 50 users can connect to the website at the same time?
Do I need to manually close the connection in the code, or does mysql handles it itself?

Comment: Why are you using both PDO and mysqli? This page: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php may be helpful.

Comment: Let's say that I do. Does it makes a difference? Are there different connections to pdo, msqli and legacy mysql? If all my pages are pdo, and I have 100 people trying to access the site, would I still get this error?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest implementing persistent PDO connections everywhere (if you are able to budget the time) and increasing max-connections if need be. This will also improve application consistency and readability.

As the link I provided in my comment explains, PDO caches persistent connections:

> "Many web applications will benefit from making persistent connections
>   to database servers. Persistent connections are not closed at the end
>   of the script but are cached and re-used when another script requests
>   a connection using the same credentials. The persistent connection
>   cache allows you to avoid the overhead of establishing a new
>   connection every time a script needs to talk to a database, resulting
>   in a faster web application."

I am not sure this will solve your connections problem, but it will improve performance and may have a positive effect on your connections issue depending on whether multiple users have the same credentials. Of course, if you are able to increase max-connections to support all concurrent users, then you can do so without implementing PDO Persistent connections.